# How can I map keyboard buttons to my mouse buttons?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, mouse, input

I have 2 extra buttons on my mouse that I would like to map as "Home" and "End"

I am able to map mouse buttons to my keyboard using xkbset, but I would like to do the reverse and map keyboard buttons to my mouse.

[Output of `xbindkeys` here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11221088/)

Comment: `xbindkeys` is what you need.  Please do a `sudo apt-get install xbindkeys*` and [edit] your question and post the output of `xbindkeys --defaults`

Comment: There it is Fabby

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Install the package `xautomation`, we need the command `xte`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xautomation
   ```
2. Install the package `x11-utils`, we need the command `xev`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install x11-utils
   ```
3. Check the code for the two mouse buttons.

   - Start the command `xev` in a terminal:

     ```
     xev
     ```
   - Move the mouse in the new window
   - Press your extra mouse buttons

   In my case, note the output `button 8` and `button 9`:

   ```
   ButtonRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
       root 0x233, subw 0x0, time 9222464, (94,21), root:(1774,85),
       state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES

   ButtonPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
       root 0x233, subw 0x0, time 9223854, (94,21), root:(1774,85),
       state 0x10, button 9, same_screen YES
   ```
4. Edit your `xbindkeys` configuration, e.g.:

   ```
   nano ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

   and add the following lines

   ```
   "xte 'key Home'"
        b:9

   "xte 'key End'"
        b:8
   ```

   Replace `b:8` and `b:9` with your numbers of `xev` output

   - from `man xte`

     ```
     key k
           Press and release key k

     keydown  k
           Press key k down

     keyup k
           Release key k
     ```
5. Kill all `kbindkeys` processes

   ```
   killall xbindkeys
   ```
6. Restart `xbindkeys` with your configuration, eg:

   ```
   xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

Comment: Hey A.B. I got it to work, thank you. One final question. I was also considering switching the extra buttons to "Up" or "Down" arrows. I tried it and it worked, but I would like the ability to hold the extra mouse buttons, and have the multiple Up/Down signals, until I release the button. (just how the native Up/Down buttons work)

Comment: Cursor Up and Down? Or Page Up and Down?

Comment: The Up/Down arrow buttons. If you were to hold Up right now, it would send it as multiple up arrow strokes until you release the button. I would like to do the same for the extra mouse buttons we are modifying.

Comment: P.S. BitTrip Runner is awesome :)

Comment: Also, I can't give you the bounty points until 21 hours, just so you know

Comment: Repetitions are difficult. I'm still looking.

Comment: Sorry, no success. Maybe you should ask a new question. :\

Comment: Is it possible to use this to press multiple keys at once