# How can I map the thumb button on a Logitech MX mouse to the back navigation for Firefox 80 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, firefox, mouse, logitech

I have spent most of the day trying to get my thumb button to navigate backwards in Firefox.

The key command I'm trying to execute is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>. That works when I click it in Firefox.

In `xev`, clicking the desired thumb button sends a KeymapNotify event, as the output below. There is no other output.

```
EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x6b5, subw 0x0, time 4046810, (92,144), root:(252,296),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967179 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x6b5, subw 0x0, time 4062605, (91,144), root:(251,296),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x6b5, subw 0x0, time 4063661, (91,144), root:(251,296),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x6b5, subw 0x0, time 4063821, (91,144), root:(251,296),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967221 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x6b5, subw 0x0, time 4064581, (91,144), root:(251,296),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0
```

Following the directions for [Ubuntu mouse configurations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations) has no effect. (unless you count the `xorg.conf` changes locking up my system, in which case it did have an effect. :) )

Since `xev` gives no useful output, `xbindkeys` is not useful.

The Shortkeys add on for Firefox does not recognize the mouse click.

This post for [Logitech MX Master Thumb Button for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973713/logitech-mx-master-thumb-button-with-ubuntu) says that the thumb button triggers the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Alt (Alt Gr)</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> key combination.  AKA, not a mouse click but a keyboard combo. So I installed `xdotool` and went to Ubuntu Settings > Keyboard shortcuts.  I created a shortcut with the following properties:

- Name:  firefox backspace remap
- Command: `xdotool key bracketleft`
- Shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

This shortcut does nothing.  If I type the command `xdotool key bracketleft` into a terminal it prints out a left bracket. If I use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> I just used to make the shortcut, nothing happens (obviously, bracketleft is not the command I ultimately want, but I'm trying to test visible output).

I installed Solaar and it recognizes my mouse.

I installed the unofficial driver logiops for Logitech mice and keyboard.  As far as I can tell it's had no effect.  I've rebooted, manually run the driver. `xev` still gives no useful output when I click the thumb button.

Ultimately, no matter what I've tried, nothing seems to recognize that this button exists.

If I switch over to Ubuntu 16.04 with the same mouse, same keyboard, and setup the shortcut, everything works fine.

I have uploaded a video to YouTube that might shed a little more light on this, I hope.

[YouTube video about how mice will not scroll in 20.04](https://youtu.be/WmR6GtiVTKM)

Comment: Does this explain xev better? https://askubuntu.com/questions/624756/how-can-i-map-keyboard-buttons-to-my-mouse-buttons

Comment: I wish it did, but there are no `ButtonRelease ` events being sent. That's what I meant by xev gives no useful output. That was a promising article, I spent a couple hours going through it before I wrote this post.  But if I'm overlooking something please let me know!

Comment: This may be driver realated because if there is no output from xev then the button is essentially "not there". I have heard of Left Handed mouse not working because there was no driver or firmware but since 18.04 there is always something for mouse & keyboard. You could search for specifics on your brand of mouse or try and reconfig Firefox so that shortcut can be replaced by something simpler like the left arrow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts

Comment: @robline I got pretty much the same issues just with the side buttons on the mouse. did you find a solution in the meantime? What I found out is  that if I hold a mouse button (or hold the click) then the malfunctioning button actually works. I assume the initial press event is only picked up when there's a button being active actually - as in, the other button that got clicked and not released. Still a bad workaround.